# custom pox controller but not able to ping in mininet code

Tags: controller, ping, mininet, sdn, pox

i have created  a custom pox controller code i which i want to forward traffic to particular mac address but when i am using ping in mininet is is not working

```
from pox.core import core
import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of
import codecs
import binascii

class Customc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node_details = {}  # Store node details here
        self.best_node = None    # Store the best node
        core.openflow.addListeners(self)
        self.read_node_details()  # Call a method to read node details

    def _handle_ConnectionUp(self, event):
        self.best_node = self.find_best_node()  # Call a method to find the best node
        if self.best_node is not None:
            self.install_flow(event.connection)  # Install flow rules

    '''def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):
        self.log_best_node("scame into method")
        if self.best_node is not None:
            if event.port == 1 and event.parsed.find('eth_dst') and event.parsed.eth_dst == self.node_details[self.best_node]['mac']:
                self.log_best_node(event.parsed.src)'''
    
    '''def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):
        packet = event.parsed  # Get the incoming packet
        # Find the best node to forward the packet to
        best_node = self.find_best_node()
    
        if best_node is not None:
            # Determine the output port for the best node (assuming you have port information)
            out_port = self.node_details[best_node]['port']
            # Create and send a flow-mod message to forward the packet to the best node
            msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
            msg.match.dl_dst = packet.dst  # Set the destination MAC address
            msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=out_port))
            event.connection.send(msg)'''
    '''def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):
        self.log_best_node("scame into method")
        if self.best_node is not None:
            mac_address = binascii.a2b_hex(self.node_details[self.best_node]['mac'].replace(":", ""))
            self.log_best_node(mac_address)
            msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
            msg.match.dl_dst = mac_address
            msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=1))  # Adjust the output port as needed
            event.connection.send(msg)
            self.log_best_node(event.parsed.src)'''

    def read_node_details(self):
        # Read and store node details from text files
        # Assume node files are named node1.txt, node2.txt, ...
        for node_id in range(1, 4):  # Adjust range based on the number of nodes
            filename = f'node{node_id}.txt'
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                details = f.read().strip()  # Read details from the file
                node_details = {}
                for item in details.split(','):
                    key, value = item.split('=')
                    node_details[key] = value
                self.node_details[node_id] = node_details

    def find_best_node(self):
        best_node = None
        best_score = float('-inf')  # Initialize with a low value

        for node_id, node_details in self.node_details.items():
            cpu_bandwidth = int(node_details['cpu_bandwidth'])
            cpu_usage = float(node_details['cpu_usage'])
            num_vehicles = int(node_details['num_vehicles'])
            num_packets_dropped = int(node_details['num_packets_dropped'])

            # Define a simple score formula (you can customize this)
            score = cpu_bandwidth + (1 - cpu_usage) + num_vehicles - num_packets_dropped

            if score > best_score:
                best_node = node_id
                best_score = score

        return best_node

    def install_flow(self, connection):
        self.log_best_node("came into install flow")
        if self.best_node is not None:
            mac_address = binascii.a2b_hex(self.node_details[self.best_node]['mac'].replace(":", ""))
            msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
            msg.match.dl_dst = (mac_address)
            self.log_best_node(msg.match.dl_dst)
            msg.priority = 10 
            msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=1))
            connection.send(msg)
    def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):
        self.log_best_node("came into install flow")
        packet = event.parsed  # Get the incoming packet
        mac_address = binascii.unhexlify(self.node_details[self.best_node]['mac'].replace(":", ""))
        msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
        msg.match.dl_dst = mac_address
        msg.priority = 10 
        msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=1))
        event.connection.send(msg)

    def log_best_node(self, src_address):
        if self.best_node is not None:
            with open('best_node_log.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(f'Source address: {src_address}, Best node: {self.best_node}\n')

def launch():
    core.registerNew(Customc)
```

and mininet code is

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import RemoteController
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.cli import CLI

def customTopology():
    net = Mininet(controller=RemoteController, link=TCLink)

    # Add controller
    c0 = net.addController('c0', ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633)

    # Add switches
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')
    s2 = net.addSwitch('s2')
    s3 = net.addSwitch('s3')

    # Add hosts
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='10.0.0.1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01')
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', ip='10.0.0.2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02')
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', ip='10.0.0.3', mac='00:00:00:00:00:03')
    h4 = net.addHost('h4', ip='10.0.0.4', mac='00:00:00:00:00:04')

    # Add links
    net.addLink(h1, s1, intfName1='h1-eth0', port1=1)
    net.addLink(h2, s1, intfName1='h2-eth0', port1=1)
    net.addLink(h3, s2, intfName1='h3-eth0', port1=1)
    net.addLink(h4, s3, intfName1='h4-eth0', port1=1)
    net.addLink(s1, s2, intfName1='s1-s2-eth3', intfName2='s2-s1-eth1', port1=3, port2=1)
    net.addLink(s2, s3, intfName1='s2-s3-eth2', intfName2='s3-s2-eth1', port1=2, port2=1)

    return net

if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = customTopology()
    net.start()

    # Find the port number of a host
    #host_to_find = net.get('s1')  # Replace 'h1' with the host you're looking for
    #switch_connected_to = host_to_find.intfList()[0].link.intf1.node

    #print(f"Port of {host_to_find.name} on {switch_connected_to.name}: {host_to_find.intfList()[0].link.intf1.name}")

    CLI(net)

    net.stop()
```

nodei.txt contains

```
mac=00:00:00:00:00:01,ip=10.0.0.1,cpu_bandwidth=1000,cpu_usage=50,num_vehicles=10,num_packets_dropped=0,port=1
```

i tried to ping but it is not forwarding packet to particular host and i am getting output as

```
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> X X X 
h2 -> X X X 
h3 -> X X X 
h4 -> X X X 
*** Results: 100% dropped (0/12 received)
mininet> h1 ping h4
PING 10.0.0.4 (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```